# Decimals on yAxis are not being displayed, even if that same code works on highcharts jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, highcharts, velocity, jsfiddle

I am having some issues I am really running out of ideas, my root of problem is this is what am I sending to highcharts, the json is unchanged and it is working fine

```
    $(function() {
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(

  {
  "meta": {
    "drilldownEnabled": false
  },
  "chart": {
  renderTo:"container",
    "additionalData": {
      "dateTime": false,
      "datetype": "string",
      "cliccable": true,
      "drillable": false,
      "drillableChart": false,
      "isCockpit": true,
      "categoryColumn": "CATEGORY",
      "categoryGroupBy": "",
      "categoryGroupByNamens": "",
      "categoryName": "CATEGORY",
      "categoryOrderColumn": "",
      "categoryOrderType": "",
      "categoryStacked": "",
      "categoryStackedType": ""
    },
    "zoomType": "xy",
    "panning": true,
    "type": "line",
    "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "heightDimType": "pixels",
    "widthDimType": "pixels",
    "plotBackgroundColor": null,
    "plotBorderWidth": null,
    "plotShadow": false,
    "borderColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "style": {
      "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "fontFamily": "",
      "fontWeight": "",
      "fontSize": ""
    },
    "events": {}
  },
  "colors": [
    "#7cb5ec",
    "#434348",
    "#90ed7d",
    "#f7a35c",
    "#8085e9",
    "#f15c80",
    "#e4d354",
    "#2b908f",
    "#f45b5b",
    "#91e8e1"
  ],
  "title": {
    "text": "",
    "style": {
      "align": "",
      "color": "",
      "fontFamily": "",
      "fontSize": "",
      "fontWeight": ""
    }
  },
  "legend": {
    "itemDistance": 0,
    "symbolPadding": 25,
    "enabled": false
  },
  "xAxis": [
    {
      "plotBands": [
        {
          "label": {
            "text": "",
            "align": "center"
          },
          "color": "",
          "from": 0,
          "to": 0
        }
      ],
      "plotLines": [
        {
          "label": {
            "text": "",
            "align": "center"
          },
          "color": "",
          "dashStyle": "",
          "value": 0,
          "width": 0
        }
      ],
      "type": "category",
      "id": 0,
      "title": {
        "customTitle": false,
        "text": "CATEGORY",
        "style": {}
      },
      "labels": {

        "style": {
          "color": "",
          "fontFamily": "",
          "fontSize": "",
          "fontWeight": ""
        },
        "align": ""
      }
    }
  ],
  "yAxis": [
    {
        allowDecimals:true,
      "plotBands": [
        {
          "label": {

            "text": "",
            "align": "center"
          },
          "color": "",
          "from": 0,
          "to": 0
        }
      ],
      "plotLines": [
        {
          "label": {

            "text": "",
            "align": "center"
          },
          "color": "",
          "dashStyle": "",
          "value": 0,
          "width": 0
        }
      ],
      "min": 0,
      "title": {
        "text": "NUMBER",
        "customTitle": false,
        "style": {
          "color": "",
          "fontFamily": "",
          "fontWeight": "",
          "fontSize": ""
        }
      },
      "labels": {
        "style": {
          "color": "",
          "fontFamily": "",
          "fontSize": "",
          "fontWeight": ""
        },
        "align": ""
      },
      "gridLineDashStyle": "$convertedTypeline",
      "minorGridLineDashStyle": "$convertedMinorTpeline"
    }
  ],
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "NUMBER",
      "dataLabels": {
        "style": {
          "color": "",
          "fontFamily": "",
          "fontWeight": "",
          "fontSize": "",
          "fontStyle": ""
        },
        "enabled": true,
        "labelFormat": "{y:,.2f}"
      },
      "data": [
        {
          "drilldown": false,
          "y": 0.1,
          "name": "CLASSE 1",
          "datetype": "string"
        },
        {
          "drilldown": false,
          "y": 0.5,
          "name": "CLASSE 2",
          "datetype": "string"
        },
        {
          "drilldown": false,
          "y": 1.3,
          "name": "CLASSE 3",
          "datetype": "string"
        }
      ],
      "selected": true,
      "tooltip": {
        "valueDecimals": 2,
        "scaleFactor": "empty",
        "ttBackColor": "#FCFFC5"
      },
      "yAxis": 0
    }
  ],
  "tooltip": {
    "borderWidth": 0,
    "borderRadius": 0,
    "followTouchMove": false,
    "followPointer": true,
    "useHTML": true,
    "backgroundColor": null,
    "style": {
      "padding": 0
    }
  },
  "lang": {
    "noData": ""
  },
  "noData": {
    "style": {
      "fontFamily": "",
      "fontSize": "",
      "color": ""
    },
    "position": {
      "align": "center",
      "verticalAlign": "middle"
    }
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "line": {
      "marker": {
        "symbol": "circle",
        "lineWidth": 2
      }
    },
    "series": {
      "events": {},
      "showCheckbox": true,
      "cursor": "pointer",
      "point": {
        "events": {}
      },
      "dataLabels": {
        "allowOverlap": true
      },
      "turboThreshold": 2000
    }
  }
}

  );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JeLrb/520/
please note this decimal values on  vertical axis,
but for some unknown reason when it comes to rendering on my application, the decimal does not apply

[image]

I even tried adding for example   tickInterval: 0.25, and it DOES separate it but it still shows 1 and 1 again and 1 again, and if i put   tickInterval: 0.50, it shows 2 times less on yAxis, which implies that it DOES work but it just refuses to show decimals.

do you have any idea what might be the problem ?
Perhaps libraries ?
Any guidance will help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why the same chart options are shown differently in jsfiddle and your environment. However, you can customize yAxis labels using [yAxis.labels.formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.formatter) function. There you should have access to values with decimals. Check demo I posted you below.

```
  formatter: function() {
    return this.value.toFixed(2);
  }
```

**Demo:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/w23bgnvp/

Comment: I will give it a try, thank you so much for shedding some light I am in dead end for past 3 days. I will let you know the results Wojciech.

Comment: You were correct, once i removed all of other functions from my velocity, and injected this one, it worked like a glove !
Someone was wise and hardcoded it to 0, and btw i was not able to see it because there are like 250 lines of code in that formatter function.
So best way for anyone that comes here later is to place this function at the END OF your formatter so it does not get ran over by something else.
Again Wojciech, thank you so much !